# Download file is corrupted asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

In my asp.net webpage, I have one `Grid` and a download `Button`. The `Grid` fill the information about the files from a shared location and download button downloads all the files after zipping.

I'm using `Ionic.Zip` library for zipping.

The below is the code, which executes when the user clicks on the download button.
The download works fine, but when I bind the files information (like name etc.) to the `GridView` control it breaks after binding the file information to the `GridView` control.

I get an error "The compressed zip folder is invalid", but when I save the zip file using the `Ionic.Zip` library it is not corrupted and I can open it manually!

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
Response.ClearContent();Response.Clear();string LogPath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LogPath"];
LogPath = Path.Combine(LogPath, Application);
//Zip File will be created when one of the file is in use during Zip.
ZipFile Zip = new ZipFile();
Zip.AddDirectory(LogPath);
string _DateTime = System.DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMyyHHmmssfff");
string ZipFileName = string.Format("ZipFile{0}.zip",_DateTime);
//Zip.Save(Response.OutputStream);
ErrorMessage.Text = Response.OutputStream.CanRead + " " + Response.OutputStream.CanWrite;
string _Path = MapPath(".");
_Path = Path.Combine(_Path, ZipFileName);
ErrorMessage.Visible = true;
Zip.Save(_Path);
// Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "filename=" + ZipFileName);
Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + ZipFileName);
//Response.ContentType = "application/zip";
Response.ContentType = "application/unknown";
Response.WriteFile(_Path);
```

Comment: try adding contentlength header

Comment: What do you mean "it breaks" and did it already work for *any kind of file download* before you seen it breaking for your current example?